# How to change of color the border in active type text?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have some problem width border when I click on input type=text. I was looking  for probably eweryone and I cant to find it.

I want to change the border color when i was click on.

I want something like that(selection in red color):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUWCi.png)

And I have something:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbgNP.png)

I was lookig for eweryone. I thought that will be in default style browser but there isn't.

Below my HTML code:

```html
<div class="search">
                
                <label for="site-search"></label>
                <input type="text" id="site-search" name="search"  placeholder="Przeszukaj Wikipedię"
                <!-- <button>Szukaj</button> -->
                <a href="#">Szukaj</a>
            </div>
```

and CSS code:

```css
input[type=text]{
   width: 350px;
   height: 32px;
   border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
   padding: 2px;
   border-top-left-radius: 2px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
   transition: .5s;
}
input[type=text]:hover{
    border-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);

}
```

Maybe someone knows how soluction this problem?

thx

I want soluction this problem but I won't do it myself.